# Noticable delay in checkmark showing/hiding when clicking on checkbox on mobile

Tags: angularjs, ipad, checkbox, label, angularjs-ng-touch

I am using the ngTouch module in Angular 1.3.12, running my site on both iPad and desktop.

The problem is specific to mobile devices (iPad).

I have a checkbox input wrapped in a label so that both checkbox and label will detect a touch:

> ```
> <label><input ng-click="doCheck()" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" ng-model="myModel"/>My label</label>
> ```

Using ngTouch's ng-click directive does appear much more responsive on the iPad, however in this case, I notice that even though I am able to touch quickly on the checkbox or label, the checkmark only toggles after a slight delay.

How can I make this toggle appear faster? Could this be related to the 300ms delay associated with ng-clicks?

Comment: You can try limiting any two way bound variables that you don't need and make them one way. To do this just prefix your models with ::

Comment: Also if you are using {{}}, replace them with ng-bind directive. It is slightly faster.